# the '.' character hexadecimal value 0x00 cannot be included in a name

Tags: ssis

While running an SSIS package with XML source and SQL Server destination, i am getting an error.Please find the attached error screen and kindly help me....

Many Thanks,
Sreekanth

[image: Error when running SSIS package with XML Source and SQL Server Destination.]

Comment: What do you think the problem is? Could it be exactly what the error message is telling you?

Comment: We don't have access to your file. Given that the error is apparently at line 315943, please look there (and *don't* post it, please!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply John... The line number mentioned in the error message is last line of the xml file. I am getting the same error for more than one file. So i am confused whether this is data issue or do i need to include any transformation..? Please advice...

Comment: Line no. 315943 is the end of file. Issue is showing in the last line of many files...!!! thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1):

ASCII null/NUL is generally regarded as a string termination character in a host of languages. I believe what you are observing is that the SSIS libraries are reading in your source XML and the presence of the string termination signals the read operation to stop.

How can you resolve it? The quick way to verify is to use a hex editor to edit the source XML file and strip out those NUL values. If the ETL runs fine, then you either need to get your source system to not put that in there. Another option would be to see whether the CDATA tag would allow that to be safely escaped. I *think* that's what it's for. Barring either of those working, I'd resort to running a preprocessing step to strip the \0 character out of the source file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @billinkc. I don't have much experience on XML parcing. How i can check whether CDATA tag would allow that NUlL value to be escaped safely.

Answer (score 0):

Allot of times this error means that your XML source has encoding specified differently in comment part and the actually the file is encoded differently. e.g  but the file might be encoded differently. SSIS will throw error if that is the case. To know what your files encoding format is...you can open the file in notepad++ or ultraedit for huge files and look at the footer details where you see line column, Dos\Windows\Unix etc. the econding will be specified there like ANSI, UTF-8 UTF-16 etc. 
in my case the encoding specified in XML comment was utf-8 but the file was utf-16 encoded. So it was throwing above error. you can change that using ultraedit or reach out to source and get it corrected.

hope that helps someone.